# avoiding data leakage with timed data and cross validation

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I'm using the [Kobe Bryant Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/kobe-bryant-shot-selection).

I wish to predict the `shot_made_flag` with `KnnRegressor`.

I'm trying to avoid data leakage by grouping the data by `season`, `year`, and `month`.

`season` is pre-existing column and `year` and `month` are columns I've added like so:

```
kobe_data_encoded['year'] = kobe_data_encoded['game_date'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('(\d{4})').findall(x)[0]))
kobe_data_encoded['month'] = kobe_data_encoded['game_date'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('-(\d+)-').findall(x)[0]))
```

Here's the full code of my pre-processing code of the features:

```
import re
# drop unnecesarry columns
kobe_data_encoded = kobe_data.drop(columns=['game_event_id', 'game_id', 'lat', 'lon', 'team_id', 'team_name', 'matchup', 'shot_id'])

# use HotEncoding for action_type, combined_shot_type, shot_zone_area, shot_zone_basic, opponent
kobe_data_encoded = pd.get_dummies(kobe_data_encoded, prefix_sep="_", columns=['action_type'])
kobe_data_encoded = pd.get_dummies(kobe_data_encoded, prefix_sep="_", columns=['combined_shot_type'])
kobe_data_encoded = pd.get_dummies(kobe_data_encoded, prefix_sep="_", columns=['shot_zone_area'])
kobe_data_encoded = pd.get_dummies(kobe_data_encoded, prefix_sep="_", columns=['shot_zone_basic'])
kobe_data_encoded = pd.get_dummies(kobe_data_encoded, prefix_sep="_", columns=['opponent'])

# covert season to years
kobe_data_encoded['season'] = kobe_data_encoded['season'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('(\d+)-').findall(x)[0]))

# covert shot_type to numeric representation
kobe_data_encoded['shot_type'] = kobe_data_encoded['shot_type'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('(\d)PT').findall(x)[0]))

# add year and month using game_date
kobe_data_encoded['year'] = kobe_data_encoded['game_date'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('(\d{4})').findall(x)[0]))
kobe_data_encoded['month'] = kobe_data_encoded['game_date'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('-(\d+)-').findall(x)[0]))
kobe_data_encoded = kobe_data_encoded.drop(columns=['game_date'])

# covert shot_type to numeric representation
kobe_data_encoded.loc[kobe_data_encoded['shot_zone_range'] == 'Back Court Shot', 'shot_zone_range'] = 4
kobe_data_encoded.loc[kobe_data_encoded['shot_zone_range'] == '24+ ft.', 'shot_zone_range'] = 3
kobe_data_encoded.loc[kobe_data_encoded['shot_zone_range'] == '16-24 ft.', 'shot_zone_range'] = 2
kobe_data_encoded.loc[kobe_data_encoded['shot_zone_range'] == '8-16 ft.', 'shot_zone_range'] = 1
kobe_data_encoded.loc[kobe_data_encoded['shot_zone_range'] == 'Less Than 8 ft.', 'shot_zone_range'] = 0

# transform game_date to date time object
# kobe_data_encoded['game_date'] = pd.to_numeric(kobe_data_encoded['game_date'].str.replace('-',''))

kobe_data_encoded.head()
```

Then I've scaled the data using `MinMaxScaler`:

```
# scaling
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled_features_df = kobe_data_encoded.copy()
column_names = ['loc_x', 'loc_y', 'minutes_remaining', 'period',
                'seconds_remaining', 'shot_distance', 'shot_type', 'shot_zone_range']
scaled_features = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(scaled_features_df[column_names])
scaled_features_df[column_names] = scaled_features
```

And grouped by the `season`, `year`, and `month` like stated above:

```
seasons_date = scaled_features_df.groupby(['season', 'year', 'month'])
```

I've been tasked with using `KFold` to find the best K using `roc_auc` score.

Here's my implementation:

```
neighbors = [x for x in range(1,50) if x % 2 != 0]
cv_scores = []
for k in neighbors:
    print('k: ', k)
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, n_jobs=-1)
    scores = []
    accumelated_X = pd.DataFrame()
    accumelated_y = pd.Series()
    for group_name, group in seasons_date:
        print(group_name)
        group = group.drop(columns=['season', 'year', 'month'])
        not_classified_df = group[group['shot_made_flag'].isnull()]
        classified_df = group[group['shot_made_flag'].notnull()]

        X = classified_df.drop(columns=['shot_made_flag'])
        y = classified_df['shot_made_flag']
        accumelated_X = pd.concat([accumelated_X, X])
        accumelated_y = pd.concat([accumelated_y, y])
        cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
        scores.append(cross_val_score(knn, accumelated_X, accumelated_y, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc'))
    cv_scores.append(scores.mean())

#graphical view
#misclassification error
MSE = [1-x for x in cv_scores]
#optimal K
optimal_k_index = MSE.index(min(MSE))
optimal_k = neighbors[optimal_k_index]
print(optimal_k)
# plot misclassification error vs k
plt.plot(neighbors, MSE)
plt.xlabel('Number of Neighbors K')
plt.ylabel('Misclassification Error')
plt.show()
```

I'm not sure if I'm dealing with the data leakage correctly in this situation 
Because if I'm accumulating the previous season data and then pass it over to `cross_val_score` I might just as-well and up with data leakage since the cv can split the data in a way that the new season data it fitted upon and the previous season data is tested upon am I right here?
If so I would like to know how to approach this situation where I would like to use `K-Fold` to find the best `k` using this timed data without having data leakage.
Is it even sensible to use `K-Fold` to split data and not split by game date to avoid data leakage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be short, as you wanna do something with sounds like timeseries, you cannot use the standard k-fold cross validation.

You would use some data from the future to predict the past, which is forbidden.

A good approach you can find here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection

```
fold 1 : training [1], test [2]
fold 2 : training [1 2], test [3]
fold 3 : training [1 2 3], test [4]
fold 4 : training [1 2 3 4], test [5]
fold 5 : training [1 2 3 4 5], test [6]
```

where the numbers are in chronolical order of your datatime